# flash[:notice] not working when redirect_to changes from http to https and vice versa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

When a user login to a system, it is in `https`

Then it goes to the home page, it is `http`

During login, depending upon certain conditions we give some messages to the users using `flash[:notice]`

But the `flash[:notice]` is not working.

When `ssl` was not implemented flash[:notice] worked fine.

`redirection` from `http` to `http` page also `flash[:notice]` works perfectly.

We have also implemented

`flash.keep`

```
redirect_to path_to_path, :flash=>{:notice=>"our message"}
```

But both of them failed.

Please suggest if anyone has faced this type of situation.

Comment: It's probably happening because after you login, there are two redirections. First one redirects user to home page, second one changes protocol from https to http. How is your SSL security implemented in application?

Comment: @MarekLipka Yes, there are two redirection. In the first redirection we are creating the flash message. In the second redirection protocol is changed. As the protocol is changed. We have implemented SSL security using `bartt-ssl-requirement` gem

Comment: @MarekLipka Your suggestion helped me a lot. I used flash.keep in both the redirection. Now it is working perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our application, there are two redirection.

In the first redirection after login we go to home page where we are creating the flash message.

In the second redirection protocol is changed for the home page.

I used `flash.keep` in both the redirection.

Now all `flash[:notice]` works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

`flash` messages are implemented using server sessions. However, depending on the server and configuration, sessions are not shared between http and https sessions. In other words, if you switch from http to https or vice-versa, the server creates two distinct user sessions.

You can check this by printing out the session ID and comparing if it's the same.

You can work around the problem by passing a parameter in the query string that represents the message (for example `redirect_to path_to_path(message: 1)` and then in the action check, if the param is present, in the view print out the message (that will be coded in the view).

Comment: We are redirecting like this `redirect_to "/#{@sgnpost.alias_post_id}?display=true"`. paths are dynamically generated. We cannot use `(message: 'our message')`. So we also tried using `redirect_to "/#{@sgnpost.alias_post_id}?display=true", :flash => { :notice => "Welcome to ..."}`. But this also did not worked.

Comment: Read my answer carefully. I suggested to not set the flash on redirect, simply pass the query. Then in the template display write the HTML to show the message and display it only if `params[:message] == "1"`

Comment: Okay, I got it. I am implementing it now. If successful, I will let you know.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me a lot. I used flash.keep in both the redirections instead of using params[:message]. Now it is working perfectly. Thanks